# Reformulation of a Frobenius norm maximization problem

Tags: optimization

This question is extended from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374279/21209) question

The original problem is to maximize the Frobenius norm of a matrix product

$max_{X\in \mathbb{D}}||B^TXA  ||_F$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the doubly stochastic matrix set

One challenge is that the size of matrix $X$ is big and I would like to reformulate it into a low memory requirement formulation.

I have tried to consider the $l_1$ version of the problem.

But yet the performance is not too good. (Mentioned in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374279/21209))

Any good suggestion?

Comment: Rein, I answered the $\ell_1$ vs. Frobenius part of this question for you over on Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374279/l1-norm-and-frobenius-norm?noredirect=1#comment802134_374279 That answer has not changed. When I recommended posting a question over here, it was specifically to ask about the *computational challenge* of implementing a large-scale version of your problem. As written, I'd say this question is enough of a duplicate of the Math.SE question to recommend closure---but a good edit should take care of that.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant Thanks, I have modified the question.

Comment: Do you want to minimize or maximize the Frobenius norm of $B^{T}XA$?  Michael Grant's answer below is written in terms of a minimization.

Comment: Wow, I just noticed that. If you do indeed want maximization then all bets are off, this is a non convex problem, and nearly all of what I have said in both posts is wrong.

Comment: I have deleted my answer for now. I can always restore it with edits if we decide that's appropriate.